# Spark Intersection is taking much time

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

I have two `RDD` namely `oldDataRDD` from Cassandra table1 and the `newDataRDD` from the Cassandra table2.

I am performing the intersection on these two `RDDs`.
The records count in these `oldDataRDD` range between **34560000** to **40000000**,
and the record count in the `newDataRDD` is almost the same as **34560000**.
The job time taken to execute the intersection is varying, it sometimes takes 7-9 minutes and sometimes it takes 30+ minute.

Is it the weird behavior of spark intersection?
Are there any better alternatives to perform the intersection of `RDD`?

Comment: It is not particularly weird. To find an intersection Spark has to hash partition (and shuffle) both datasets. It is an expensive operation and performance will very depending on a data.

Comment: are there any alternates?

Comment: In general case no. In practice all depends on your data. and requirements. Bloom filter could be a place to start.

Comment: Thanks for the info :-)