# Spark intersection implementation

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

How does Spark implement intersection method? Does it require 2 RDDs to colocate on a single machine?

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34542623/spark-intersection-is-taking-much-time) it says that it uses hashtables, which is a bit odd as it's probably not scalable and sorting both rdds and then comparing item by item might have provided a more scalable solution.

Any thoughts on the subject are welcome

Comment: Just guessing the implementation: If you have multiple subsets of `A` such that their union would equate to `A`, as well as multiple subsets of `B`; wouldn't it be true that `union(intersection(A1, B1), intersection(A2, B2), ... intersection(An, Bn))` be equal to `intersection(A, B)`? If that's true, then maybe that's how it works, i.e., `A1` and `B1` are just partitions/subsets of `A` and `B`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It definitely doesn't need the RDDs to colocate on a single machine. You can just look at the [code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L632) for the details. Looks like it uses a cogroup.